# how to return a calculation in django rest framework and let a user filter it

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

hi i think i asked a similar question before which was to print it but i wasn't able to get any answer which worked. So how do i show a calculation and filter it, here is my code below of which i am getting a users co-ordinates and i am getting the list of sellers co-ordinates and then putting them into this calculation below

```
def calc_distance(self, lat_a, long_a, lat_b, long_b):
        EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES = 3958.761
        """all angles in degrees, result in miles"""
        lat_ab = radians(lat_a)
        lat_b = radians(lat_b)
        delta_long = radians(long_a - long_b)
        cos_x = (
               sin(lat_ab) * sin(lat_b) +
               cos(lat_ab) * cos(lat_b) * cos(delta_long)
            )
        return acos(cos_x) * EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES
```

then i want to return all the sellers with the distance of each one. And if possible let the user filter the distance
here is my code so far

```
def calc_distance(self, lat_a, long_a, lat_b, long_b):
        EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES = 3958.761
        """all angles in degrees, result in miles"""
        lat_ab = radians(lat_a)
        lat_b = radians(lat_b)
        delta_long = radians(long_a - long_b)
        cos_x = (
               sin(lat_ab) * sin(lat_b) +
               cos(lat_ab) * cos(lat_b) * cos(delta_long)
            )
        return acos(cos_x) * EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES


class Listsellers(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    queryset = Seller_account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SellerAccountSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    
    def calc_distance(self, lat_a, long_a, lat_b, long_b):
        EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES = 3958.761
        """all angles in degrees, result in miles"""
        lat_ab = radians(lat_a)
        lat_b = radians(lat_b)
        delta_long = radians(long_a - long_b)
        cos_x = (
               sin(lat_ab) * sin(lat_b) +
               cos(lat_ab) * cos(lat_b) * cos(delta_long)
            )
        return acos(cos_x) * EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES
    def calc_dist(self):
        user_long = Users.objects.username.longitude
        user_lat = Users.objects.username.latitude
        seller_lat = Seller_account.objects.latitude
        seller_long = Seller_account.objects.latitude
        lat_a = user_lat
        print(lat_a)
        long_a = user_long
        print(long_a)
        lat_b = seller_lat
        print(lat_b)
        long_b = seller_long
        print(long_b)
        distance = Users.objects.calc_distance(self, lat_a, long_a, lat_b, long_b)
        print(distance) 

    ##def get_queryset(self):
        #queryset = Seller_account.objects.all()
       # self.calc_dist()
        #return Response(queryset)
```

is there something i am missing?

Comment: @Rahul Gupta from your profile it seems you have a lot of experience in django rest framework, so could you help me please with this question. Thank you

Comment: @Tom Christie  from your profile it seems you have a lot of experience in django rest framework, so could you help me please with this question. Thank you